# Encrypting/Decrypting(Using AES) Large files and transferring over HTTP

Tags: java, http, encryption, cryptography, base64

My requirement requires me to encrypt files using AES and send it over HTTP.On server, I'm reading the file content into a byte[],encrypting it using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding  and then doing a base 64 encode and writing it into the stream from the server.The consumer(mobile device applications) retrieves this encrypted and encoded data and does decoding and then decryption and writes the plain data into a file of fixed format.It all works fine for small files.But I feel that this is a naive way of doing it.I can see this causing high memory consumption on Server as well devices and even leading to application crash when I consider files >100MB in size.Please advice me how to proceed.I searched quite a bit,while I found ways to encrypt,none of them seem to efficient.
Let me know if required,I'll post my code and any other additional information.Thank You.

Comment: I can give you one short advice: use streams. Example for encryption - http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/UsingCipherOutputStream.htm and for Base64 http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just require transport security then you should simply go for TLS. If you are stuck with this protocol or if you require application level security (storage on server) then you should use streams, as [user1516873](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1516873/user1516873) already indicated. Note that HTTP can handle binary data, so there is no technical need for base 64 encoding. If you do require base 64, it would be beneficial to use a encoding/decoding stream for that as well. Guava seems to implement a good interface for base64 encoding, including [stream support](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html#encodingStream(java.io.Writer)).

Note that sending encrypted data over an untrusted network does not protect you against change. If *padding oracles* apply then you may not even be providing confidentiality, which is the whole idea of using encryption in the first place.

Comment: Both [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and [Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) have implementations of Base64 streams.

Comment: hi owlstead, Yes we require application level security also.We are using https in fact.As you said,I previously didn't use base 64 encoding but that was causing some data loss when received on the other side.So they were not able to decrypt.To avoid that, we employed a final layer of base 64 encoding.Can you elaborate in this regard plz.thank you